# What are some good WPF Datagrid usage examples?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Where can I find some good examples of populating the WPF datagrid with data using LINQ?

Answer (score 2):

[Jamie Rodriguez](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2008/08/13/dabbling-around-the-new-wpf-datagrid-part-1.aspx)

[Vincent Sibal](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/tags/DataGrid+Concepts/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGrid.aspx) includes an article on the topic. There is also an [sample application](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/22/wpf-datagrid-and-the-wpftoolkit-have-released.aspx) that should give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

try to follow this example.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx

and those articles

http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx

in adding try to follow this thread.

[WPF DataGrid Good Tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572921/wpf-datagrid-good-tutorials)

Regards.