# WPF DataGrid Good Tutorials?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Could anyone points me to good WPF DataGrid tutorials on the internet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are good ones, the second one is old but still good enough :)

[www.wpftutorial.net](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

[WPF DataGrid Examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly a tutorial, but if you plan to do much with styling the DataGrid I've found this blog post useful:
[Styling Microsoft’s WPF datagrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Check this one:

[DataGrid Feature Walkthrough](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: The link attached is broken

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**.

Comment: But this is all about MVVM, what I need is good tutorials about the WPF DataGrid control (binding, styling, animations, validation). Anyways, thanks for your effort :)